# Creating a UDF in excel with a soap call, but returns #Value! What am I doing wrong?

Tags: web-services, excel, soap, user-defined-functions

Here is the code I wrote.
More Information to the web service is at https://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/Service/KPSPublic.asmx?op=TCKimlikNoDogrula

```
Function tckimlik(ad As String, soyad As String, tckn As Double, dy As Integer) As String
Dim responseText As String
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim sEnv As String
    Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
    Dim startPos, endPos, openTag, closeTag, startTagPos, sid As String
    sURL = "http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS/TCKimlikNoDogrula"
    sEnv = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">"
    sEnv = sEnv & " <soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<TCKimlikNoDogrula xmlns=""http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS""> "
    sEnv = sEnv & "<TCKimlikNo>"
    sEnv = sEnv & tckn
    sEnv = sEnv & "</TCKimlikNo>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<Ad>"
    sEnv = sEnv & ad
    sEnv = sEnv & "</Ad>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<Soyad>"
    sEnv = sEnv & soyad
    sEnv = sEnv & "</Soyad>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "<DogumYili>"
    sEnv = sEnv & dy
    sEnv = sEnv & "</DogumYili>"
    sEnv = sEnv & " </TCKimlikNoDogrula>"
    sEnv = sEnv & " </soap:Body>"
    sEnv = sEnv & "</soap:Envelope>"

With xmlhtp
        .Open "post", sURL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Host", "tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        .setRequestHeader "soapAction", "http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS/TCKimlikNoDogrula"
        .send sEnv
        xmlDoc.LoadXML .responseText
        responseText = .responseText
    End With
tckimlik = responseText


End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: are you getting response text?

Comment: If you run that function from a sub instead of from a worksheet you'll get a more useful error message...